# Trying to prove that every connected graph which has only even degreed vertices contains no bridges

Tags: graph-theory

First take note, our professor likes to change terms from our book.  I have the following:

Assume we have a connected graph $G$ where all of the vertices have even degree.   If we assume it does have a “cut-vertex” / bridge.  Let $u$ and $v$ be the two vertices that connects to form our edge $e$.   So know we will have two components (call one $H$ and $I$)  consisting of $G - e$.  Originally all of the vertices of $G$ had a even degree.  But since we have removed one edge from at least a vertex in each component, that means we have an odd vertex in each component ($\mathrm{even}\,– 1 = \mathrm{odd}$).  But by the corollary (1.5 in book) to the First Theorem of Graph Theory, every graph must have a even number of odd vertices, which neither component of $G$ has.

Is this sufficient?  I have read other proofs on here and not sure if mine will work.

Comment: yes, it's ok.$ $